# Making an animating main menu

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

What would be the best way to make a main menu for a game? I would prefer it to be UIButtons. More specifically, what would be the best way of animating the buttons? For example, an animation on the view load of the buttons going in, then the buttons going out when a menu option is selected and then new buttons (the submenu) animated back in. I have never done any animating before so I would like to know the best way. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of animation is very easy using UIKit:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    button1.frame = <new frame>;
    button2.frame = <new frame>;
}];
```

This will animate the frame from the current frame, to the specified frame over the given duration (0.5 seconds). If the current frame is offscreen and the new frame is the final position you want then the buttons will move to their correct position over 0.5 seconds.

The following properties of UIView are animatable in this fashion:

- frame
- bounds
- center
- transform
- alpha
- backgroundColor
- contentStretch

The [Animations section of the View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html) has more info.